# Stop showing events after the end_date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have the following code on my php page to show events from mysql database that start today:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sort_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
  AND authorize = 1
ORDER BY sort_date ASC
```

It is only showing calendar events starting TODAY, not yesterday or last week and this code is working nicely.

Some events have a longer duration than 24 hours, so we would like the event to not show "after" the end_date

So in essence, it shows only events starting NOW and stops showing after the end_date.

Any help on changing the code to keep an event until the end date would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How is the duration represented?

Comment: with a field called: end_date.

Start date field is called: date

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `events` rows have a `sort_date` and an `end_date` in them, here's what you need.

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM events
 WHERE sort_date >= CURDATE()
   AND end_date  < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    etc etc etc
```

The expression `< CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` chooses all items for which the end_date is sometime up until, but not including, the first moment of tomorrow.

Notice that you don't need all that stuff with `DATE_FORMAT()` that you showed in your question; you can do comparisons directly on dates.

Comment: I will give it a shot. I guess the only way to tell if it works is when the day comes. :-)  Thanks!

Comment: Umm, some fake records for testing?

Comment: The site is live...but I guess I could throw something in there. I did throw something in and will let you know if it is still there tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Ollie, I added a test event yesterday that started yesterday and had an end date of today. I assumed the event would still be showing today, but it is not. Any thoughts?
Here was the actual code: 
SELECT *   FROM events  WHERE sort_date >= CURDATE()    AND end_date  < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND authorize = 1 ORDER BY sort_date ASC